# como hacer un generador de letras y números para phpmyadmin en un campo id que se genere automaticamente

Tags: phpmyadmin

Deseo crear un id que al insertar un dato pueda automáticamente en este campo agregar un código con letras y números, como es posible hacer eso?

Comment: no es clara.... con un  stored procedure o algo asi?  que has logrado hacer?

Comment: la idea es que tengo un campo id y quiero que cuando yo inserte un nuevos datos el automaticamente genere un codigo en el campo id de letras y numeros como por decir un autoincremento

Comment: todo desde el phpmyadmin si?... bueno. realmente no importa.  podrias hacerlo con un storedprocedure

Comment: si todo desde hay

Comment: que pena como funciona eso de storedprocedure

Comment: Debes realizas dos cosas

1. un trigger
2. storeprocedure

Answer (score -1):

deberias actualizar tu pregunta para que cumpla con las condiciones https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

con lo que preguntas te sugiero que revises y pruebes:

Triggers -  disparadores

1. ejemplo 1  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Av8T_Nlvt9s
2. ejemplo 2 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kDu_5F159QA

Store Procedures - procedimientos almacenados

1. ejemplo 1 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dwVj_g3TpZ4
2. ejemplo 2 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Gy8-hCA8a0

//////////////////////////////

un trigger que funciona seria algo asi:

tengo una tabla que se llama test_tabla
que tiene dos campos uno entero que se llama id y uno varchar que se llama id_Autocreado

```
CREATE TRIGGER `actualizar_id_automatico` 
BEFORE INSERT ON `test_tabla` 
FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.id_autocreado = SUBSTRING(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE( TO_BASE64(MD5(RAND())), '=',''),'+',''),'/',''), 2, FLOOR(10+RAND()*31))
```